# How to show a dismissible popover using a <i></i> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a dismissible popover using Bootstrap 3 and `<i>` tag. I can't use `<a>` tag there. My code is below.

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle infoCirc" data-content="{{helpSrv.helpInfo['dashboardTooltipId']}}" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover"  id="dashboardTooltipId" data-placement="bottom"></i>
```

Currently, I am using `data-trigger = "hover"`. But I want to use `data-trigger = "focus"` so that the popover will come when I click the `<i>` and disappear when I click outside `<i>`. But, `data-trigger = "focus"` doesn't work with `<i>` tag. It works only with `<a>` tag.

I can't use `<a>` there. `data-content` comes properly. There is no problem in it.

Is there any way to fix it ??

Comment: does i tag have focus event? No!

Comment: why can't you use  `<a>` tag?

Comment: because they are in a `nav-tabs`. If I use `<a>` there then it shows `<i>` as different element and comes out of the tab.

Comment: damn hard to use css to make it stay in the nav-tabs

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: below what?????

Answer (score 0):

```
.infoCirc {display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-examples) you can't use the dismissible popover without a  tag. For this reason, maybe try doing the following:

```
<a href="#" data-content="{{helpSrv.helpInfo['dashboardTooltipId']}}" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus"  id="dashboardTooltipId" data-placement="bottom" role="button"><i class="fa fa-info-circle infoCirc"></i></a>
```

You can see the JSFiddle used here: https://jsfiddle.net/sanity1123/f1gacehv/1/

You will notice that in the JSFiddle, I have used nav-tabs also and everything is working.